# Issue with option arguments in GNAT.Command_Line

Tags: command-line-arguments, ada, gnat

I'm having an issue parsing input arguments in Ada using the `GNAT.Command_Line` package. I've modeled my approach based off resources such as [this Ada Gem](https://www.adacore.com/gems/gem-139-master-the-command-line-part-2) as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70259135/how-to-copy-data-from-string-access-to-ada-string), but can't seem to get the argument-accepting switches working correctly.

`main.adb`:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;           use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Command_Line;          use Command_Line;

procedure Main is
   CLS : Command_Line_State;
begin
   Parse_Command_Line (State => CLS);
end Main;
```

`Command_Line.ads`:

```
with Ada.Containers.Vectors; use Ada.Containers;
with Ada.Directories;        use Ada.Directories;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;  use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Text_IO;            use Ada.Text_IO;
with Gnat.Command_Line;      use Gnat.Command_Line;
with Gnat.OS_Lib;            use Gnat.OS_Lib;
with Gnat.Strings;           use Gnat.Strings;

package Command_Line is

   type Output_Type is (CSV, TXT);

   type Filename_Record is record
      Was_Given : Boolean;
      Filename  : Unbounded_String;
      Path      : Unbounded_String;
   end record;

   package Filename_Vectors is new Vectors (Positive, Filename_Record);

   type Command_Line_State is record
      Filenames        : Filename_Vectors.Vector;
      Interactive_Mode : Boolean := False;
      Output_Format    : Output_Type;
   end record;

   procedure Parse_Command_Line (State : in out Command_Line_State);

end Command_Line;
```

`Command_Line.adb`:

```
package body Command_Line is

   procedure Parse_Command_Line(State : in out Command_Line_State) is
      Configuration : Command_Line_Configuration;
      In_Path       : aliased Gnat.Strings.String_Access;
      Out_Path      : aliased Gnat.Strings.String_Access;
      Interactive   : aliased Boolean := False;
      CSV_Format    : aliased Boolean := False;
   begin
  
      Define_Switch (Config      => Configuration,
                     Output      => In_Path'Access,
                     Switch      => "-i",
                     Long_Switch => "--inpath",
                     Help        => "Supplies an external path for case files not colocated with the program",
                     Argument    => "PATH");
      Define_Switch (Config      => Configuration,
                     Output      => Out_Path'Access,
                     Switch      => "-o",
                     Long_Switch => "--outpath",
                     Help        => "Identifies an external path or directory to write output data to",
                     Argument    => "PATH");
      Define_Switch (Config      => Configuration,
                     Output      => Interactive'Access,
                     Switch      => "-n",
                     Long_Switch => "--interactive",
                     Help        => "Places program into interactive mode");
      Define_Switch (Config      => Configuration,
                     Output      => CSV_Format'Access,
                     Switch      => "-c",
                     Long_Switch => "--csv",
                     Help        => "Output data in CSV, rather than TXT format");
      Getopt (Configuration);
  
      declare
         In_Path_Unbounded  : Unbounded_String := To_Unbounded_String (In_Path.all);
         Out_Path_Unbounded : Unbounded_String := To_Unbounded_String (Out_Path.all);
      begin
         Put_Line ("Input file path:  '" & To_String (In_Path_Unbounded) & "'.");
         Put_Line ("Output file path: '" & To_String (Out_Path_Unbounded) & "'.");
      end;
  
      if Interactive then
         Put_Line ("Interactive mode (-n, --interactive) was set to: True.");
      else
         Put_Line ("Interactive mode (-n, --interactive) was set to: False.");
      end if;
 
      if CSV_Format then
         Put_Line ("CSV formatting mode (-c, --csv) was set to:      True.");
      else
         Put_Line ("CSV formatting mode (-c, --csv) was set to:      False.");
      end if;
  
   end Parse_Command_Line;

end Command_Line;
```

Note that some structure is present for the final end use application. When I run the program from a PowerShell window with the following options:

```
.\main.exe -i INPATH -o OUTPATH -n -c
```

I get the following result:

```
Input file path:  ''.
Output file path: ''.
Interactive mode (-n, --interactive) was set to: True.
CSV formatting mode (-c, --csv) was set to:      True.
```

How do I modify my existing code so that the `Getopt` parser and `GNAT.Command_Line` correctly capture the arguments (i.e. `INPATH` and `OUTPATH`) for string-accepting options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to add an appropriate character to both the `Switch` and `Long_Switch` parameters.

In `g-comlin.ads`, the description of `Define_Switch` reads (see also [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/ada/libgnat/g-comlin.ads;h=a2d90716a4ce7c8460161984786a3dc00292a754;hb=HEAD#l608)):

```
procedure Define_Switch
  (Config      : in out Command_Line_Configuration;
   Switch      : String := "";
   Long_Switch : String := "";
   Help        : String := "";
   Section     : String := "";
   Argument    : String := "ARG");
--  Indicates a new switch. The format of this switch follows the getopt
--  format (trailing ':', '?', etc for defining a switch with parameters).
```

While the description of `getopt` reads (in the same file, see also [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/ada/libgnat/g-comlin.ads;h=a2d90716a4ce7c8460161984786a3dc00292a754;hb=HEAD#l390)):

```
--  Switches is a string of all the possible switches, separated by
--  spaces. A switch can be followed by one of the following characters:
--
--   ':'  The switch requires a parameter. There can optionally be a space
--        on the command line between the switch and its parameter.
--
--   '='  The switch requires a parameter. There can either be a '=' or a
--        space on the command line between the switch and its parameter.
--
--   '!'  The switch requires a parameter, but there can be no space on the
--        command line between the switch and its parameter.
--
--   '?'  The switch may have an optional parameter. There can be no space
--        between the switch and its argument.
```

So, adding a colon (`:`) to the arguments of both `Switch` and `Long_Switch` will do the trick. For example:

```
Define_Switch (Config      => Configuration,
               Output      => In_Path'Access,
               Switch      => "-i:",          --  <<< !!!
               Long_Switch => "--inpath:",    --  <<< !!!
               Help        => "Supplies an external path for case files not colocated with the program",
               Argument    => "PATH");
```

Adapting the `Switch` and `Long_Switch` parameters for both `-i` and `-o` will now given the desired result:

```
$ ./obj/main -i "Foo" -o "Bar" -n -c
Input file path:  'Foo'.
Output file path: 'Bar'.
Interactive mode (-n, --interactive) was set to: True.
CSV formatting mode (-c, --csv) was set to:      True.
```

Comment: This helps a ton! I was also looking for a good source of the Ada standard libraries and GNAT packages - this addresses the question and more!